# How to determine how long a recursive fibonacci algorithm will take for larger values if I have the time for the smaller values?

Tags: recursion, fibonacci

I have used the time library and timed how long the recursive algorithm takes to calculate the fib numbers up to 50. Give those number, is there a formula I can use to determine how long it would have potentially taken to calculate fib(100)?

Times for smaller values:

```
Fib(40): 0.316 sec
Fib(80): 2.3 years
Fib(100): ???
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends very much on the algorithm in use.  The direct computation takes constant time.  The recursive computation without memoization is exponential, with a base of phi.  Add memoization to this, and it drops to logarithmic time.

The only one that could fit your data is the exponential time.  Doing the basic math ...

```
(2.3 years / 0.316 sec) ** (1.0/40)
gives us
base = 1.6181589...
```

Gee, look at that!  Less than one part in 10^4 more than phi!

Let t(n) be the time to compute Fib(n).
We can support the hypothesis that

```
t(n) = phi * t(n-1)
Therefore,
t(100) = phi^(100-80) * t(80)
```

I trust you can finish from here.

Comment: Why is the the t(n) formula and the t(100) formula different from each other? I am not too sure where u get the 80 from. Could you explain the formula a bit more please so that I can under what exactly is happening

Comment: They are different because one is the general form for t(n) defined in terms of t(n-1); the other compounds this single-step formula for a leap of 20 steps.  Given that first equation, find t(n+1) in terms of t(n-1).  Then extend to t(n+2).  Now do you see the pattern?

Comment: I still dont quite understand :/ Could you show me a few more steps

Comment: *Given that first equation, find t(n+1) in terms of t(n-1).*  This is a direct algebraic substitution.  Try it first.